# Access the recently inserted data in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have my files in the S3 like `bucketname/level1/20210321/00/...`

Where `20210321` is the date string followed by hours.

A new folder will be inserted in the bucket every day and the name would be `year+month+day` and has the subfolders for hourly data.

How to access the most recently inserted data most probably the data of the previous day?

Comment: How do you actually want to _use_ the data? I'm asking this because there might be a different approach, such as triggering an AWS Lambda function to run some code when an object is uploaded. Please Edit your question to add more details, such as how you'll be using the object, whether it is always just a single object you want, and how many objects there are in the bucket (eg hundreds or millions?).

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical way to ask S3 to access "the most recent data".

If you know the name of the folder that would have been generated, you can supply it as a `Prefix` to the `list_buckets()` command and only objects inside that 'directory' will be returned. You can then determine the 'latest' file via its `Key` or `LastModified` date.